# Tomcat 7 throwing error for jsp:include tag with jsp:param having jsp comments at the start of the line

Tags: jsp, tomcat7

I've a jsp page 'file1.jsp' where I've JSP include 'file2.jsp' as follows. When I try to run this in `Tomcat 7` I receive an error as follows, where as the same runs fine in `Websphere 6`

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Expecting "jsp:param" standard action with "name" & "value" attributes

file1.jsp includes file2.jsp as follows (every line of file1.jsp has a comment at the beginning of line)

```
<%--line 1--%>       <jsp:include page="file2.jsp" >
<%--line 2--%>       <jsp:param name="<param name>" value="<param value>" />
<%--line 3--%>       </jsp:include>
```

When I move all this 3 lines in one line as follows, Tomcat 7 runs fine.

```
<%--line 1--%>       <jsp:include page="<other jsp file reference>" > <jsp:param name="<param name>" value="<param value>" /> </jsp:include>
```

Can someone advise why `Tomcat 7` is throwing error in first place? Having comments at the beginning of each line should not be a problem I think. Please advise.

Comment: You mean you actually have scriptlet comments in the body of the jsp include? It's not clear what your exact source i'd

Comment: I've edited the description to explain it .. file1.jsp includes file2.jsp .. the comments are present in file1.jsp page on each line

Answer (score 0):

Cannot have comments inside include.  Its a bug in Jasper JSP engine since 2001 and doesn't seem like its ever going to be fixed.

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1433